# NodeJS equivalent to bytes in Java

Tags: java, node.js

Im looking at some code in java, and I see lots of code using byte[], what is the equivalent to all of this in NodeJS / Javascript?

Here is the piece of code im looking at, Input is any base64 string

```
    byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
    System.arraycopy(byteArray, 0, ivBytes, 0, 16);
    byte[] encryptedTextBytes = new byte[(byteArray.length - ivBytes.length)];
    System.arraycopy(byteArray, 16, encryptedTextBytes, 0, encryptedTextBytes.length);
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Why do you want to use raw byte arrays in JS?

Comment: [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

`byte` is one of several primitive number data types in Java. Primitive data types specify the size and type of variable values. For instance, a `byte` takes the size of 1 byte and can store whole numbers from -128 to 127. Similarly `short` takes 2 bytes, `int` takes 4 bytes... so on and so forth. Refer [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_data_types.asp) for a complete list of data types with their respective sizes.

Unlike Java, Javascript has only one type of number and it stores numbers as double precision floating point values using 64 bits. So technically, there is no equivalent number type in JavaScript to the Java number types `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` and `float`. We use `var`, `let` and `const` to declare variables in JavaScript and all those variables will be equivalent to `double` data type in Java.